# Sort comparison not matching Collection.sort

Tags: java, sorting

I'm writing a test to check a table of file names is sorted correctly, however the sort being used in the app is different to the `Collections.sort` that Java uses, basically the special characters are showing before the alpha characters.

I have no access to the code to see what sort algorithm the program is using so wanted to know was there any way to sort my array that will match the actual array? I've tried the `List` sort also but its the same output as the `Collections.sort`.

```java
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> namesSorted = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=1; i <= tableCount; i++){
    WebElement filename = this.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr["+i+"]/th"));
    names.add(filename.getText());
    namesSorted.add(filename.getText());

}

Collections.sort(namesSorted);

return namesSorted.equals(names);
```

### Example output

#### Array Sorted

```
[ABC_Firm_filename1, ABC_Firm_filename1, A_Firm_filename1, A_Firm_filename1]
```

#### Actual Array

```
[A_Firm_filename1, A_Firm_filename1, ABC_Firm_filename1, ABC_Firm_filename1]
```

Comment: You'll need to find out what ordering you need, and write a `Comparator` which uses that ordering.

Comment: "I have no access to the code to see what sort algorithm the program is using" Well then that's impossible.

Comment: Ok so ill have to do some searching, I was hoping there was some sort of algorithm that was commonly used I could use instead of Collection.sort

Comment: The sorting algorithm itself is likely immaterial. What matters is how the elements are being compared. You are sorting the full strings by their natural order (i.e., lexicographically). Obviously, that is not how the third-party app is comparing the elements. If you have to deduce how to compare the elements, then you should consider the context. What do these "names" mean? Perhaps each name is made up of three "properties", joined by `_`, compared (not necessarily as strings) one after the other. In short, you need to implement a `Comparator`, not find a different sorting algorithm.

Comment: In addition to what Slaw said, you can use the Rules based collator to give different characters different weights and thus a different sort order. You would use it as a Comapator. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html

Comment: You should really declare your lists with the interface i.e. `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>()`